# HTML5 form validation mechanism: set invalidate after server side validation

Tags: php, html, forms, css, validation

OK, title is so strange, that I should of course tell what is going on :). I'm creating a HTML5 form. I want that form to be fully validated using HTML5 new techniques, and CSS3 new pseudoclasses (of course I remember about server side validation). I will give an example:

HTML:

```
<input type="email" value="">
```

CSS:

```
input:invalid {color: #fff; box-shadow: 0 0 5px #f00;}
```

As we all know: *The good validation is the one that is strictly the same at users browser and on server.* So if I allow user to enter email number only, and server will accept letters it is a mistake. If user can enter numbers and server will not accept it is a mistake.

What is the problem? I'm asking a user for an email. User enter asd@asd which is a perfectly validate email in HTML5 nomenclature (asd can be localhost, so dot is not needed). That's why the input is validated, and everything is OK. Now, I'm sending this email to my PHP script, which is MUCH MORE demanding. For example, it:

PHP

```
function Validate($mail) {
    $validate = true;

    // Parse mail
    if (!filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) $validate = false;

    // Check DNS RR
    $host = explode('@',$mail);
    $host = array_pop($host);
    if ($host == '') $validate = false;
    else if (!checkdnsrr($host,'MX')) $validate = false;

    return $validate;
}
```

So email asd@asd of course does not pass this validation.

**Is there any mechanism that allows me to suggest the browser back that this email is still not good, but using HTML5 methods?**

More precisely. I wrote a PHP form class wchich at first checks for POST data, and then render the form. So if something is missing, I can render the form but using the POST data sended, to not forget input values. It is a common method for doing things like that.

**So I'm rendering the input email after PHP know that email is invalid but HTML5 thinks it is valid.** More code (really fragments to show You the idea...):

```
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
if (Validate($email)) {
    // do whatever You want with the form
    header("Location: /success-congratulations-great-form-hoooray");
}
else {
    echo "<form>...";
    echo "<input type="email" value=\"$email\">"; // this $email is important here!
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" ... />
    echo "</form>";
}
```

Is there a chance to suggest browser This input is invalidate? I thought about echo'ing some kind of `<script>` only if validation was wrong. But I'm stuck here.

I think that this question, example and answer will be useful to many, many people that want to make a form that meets standarts, but missed something...

Thx for Your replies and best regards!

**UPDATE**
Really no ideas how can I achieve this? I'm considering starting a bounty :).

Comment: PS. Great article here on this subject: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/html5forms/

Comment: and also that could help : http://html5pattern.com/

Comment: Thx for great link :). Question still opened :).

Comment: @audre7 I answer my own question. Could You please take a look, and say what do You think about it? Any help will be much appreciated :). Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have answered my own question. What a selfish thing. If PHP return invalidate, then we can echo

```
echo '<input name="mail" .... data-validate="This email address does not exist" />';
```

Then after all include javascript, that checks if input has its own data-validate attribute. If yes, set custom validity message (on document ready) for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var elements = $('input[data-validate]');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { 
        var error = $(elements[i]).attr('data-validate');
        elements[i].setCustomValidity(error);
        $(elements[i]).removeAttr('data-validate');
    }
});
```

In this case, we can use html5 validation mechanism AFTER php validation return errors. And the same errors that php has, are returned to user. **WHAT A GREAT AND SEMANTIC SOLUTION!!!!**
And You can enter few different messages if input is not ok. For example "Domain not exist", "Mail hasnt got @ in it!", etc...

Hope it helps someone... And what do You think about this solution? 
I will wait for comments, and if someone +1 me, I will mark it as answered... As I'm feeling strange with answering myself.

**UPDATE**
Things aren't so easy, as I thought. This isn't a 100% good answer, however, it is a good idea :). The problem is, that after setting custom validity, the form cannot be submitted anymore. So Javascript should also trigger the submit click function, and then reset all custom validity to init state.

**Real answer**

So... It is not a good idea to do this that way. Let the standarts catch up reality and lets wait till the times, when browsers really check for existency of emails. Till this time, do whatever You can on browser side to validate, and left the main, strong validation to server side. If something goes wrong after all, use You own mechanisms of error reporting, and do not try to reflect them back from php to html5 using jquery. As this is too complicated, and not worth Your time :). If someone has another idea, or know how to do this, please write another answer. I will read it, and mark it as resolved. Until that time, I think that my "do this another way" answer is good enough, to aprove it, after few days of research.

In few words: let the html5 validate You form as good as html5 can, and if strong server side validation refuse this form, make a nice information what went wrong, and what the user should improve to validate.

Thx You all for Your answers, best regards.

Comment: There are little mistakes in JS code. I will correct them as fast as I can. Please do not downvote :). But the idea is clear :).

Comment: That solution just sounds great :) But if you check with js first, why php have to return errors (even if you still have to check in php, i agree that) ? don't you check the same pattern/data in js ?  I mean, with html5 pattern you can check if there's or not an @. It prevents a page refreshing ? Or i just not understand everything (that could be true :) )

Comment: Not at all... You just enter input type=email. HTML5 treat asd@asd as a good mail. Then, PHP throw that email asd@asd is not valid, and render this input with data-validate error. And then JS is just used to set Custom Validity depending on that error... I know it is complicated, but the other way to verify email is using patterns. And patterns are complicated for mails, and cannot check for example if domain exists. So php verification is always "stronger". So html5 validate input, while php don't. And this mechanism I think can send errors from php to html5 using html5 build in validation...

Comment: OMG, I read that, and it makes sense, but it is hard to tell it clearly :). I can post code fragments in that way... (if something is unclear). Thx for opinion, it is great that such a comunity exists, and You are not alone with Your (weird) thoughts :). Best Regards :).

Answer (score 0):

Awhile ago, i had the same problem with e-mail validation when I was trying to validate an email with regex. I searched the web and found this function....

```
function validateMail($email) {
    $isValid = true;
    $atIndex = strrpos($email, "@");
    if (is_bool($atIndex) && !$atIndex) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $domain = substr($email, $atIndex+1);
        $local = substr($email, 0, $atIndex);
        $localLen = strlen($local);
        $domainLen = strlen($domain);
        if ($localLen < 1 || $localLen > 64) {
            return false;
        }
        else if ($domainLen < 1 || $domainLen > 255) {
            return false;
        }
        else if ($local[0] == '.' || $local[$localLen-1] == '.') {
            return false;
        }
        else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $local)) {
            return false;
        }
        else if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.]+$/', $domain)) {
            return false;
        }
        else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $domain)) {
            return false;
        }
        else if(!preg_match('/^(\\\\.|[A-Za-z0-9!#%&`_=\\/$\'*+?^{}|~.-])+$/',
                       str_replace("\\\\","",$local))) {
            if (!preg_match('/^"(\\\\"|[^"])+"$/', str_replace("\\\\","",$local))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if ($isValid && !(checkdnsrr($domain,"MX") || checkdnsrr($domain,"A"))) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return $isValid;
}
```

In the article it said that the function is based on RFC-5322 standard. It never failed me.

Comment: Thx for Your reply :). Mail regex are really complicated, and this is a great example, but this is not actually answer to my question. I know that my question is a little complicated, but what is important is how to suggest to HTML5 email input, that it is not valid even if the browser think it is. I tried to do a little research, and I think that there is no other way, then echoing a script that manipulate with validate, notvalidate CSS3 pseudoclass... Thx for Your reply, it isn't an answer, but it is realy helpful, +1. Best regards!

Comment: I haven't used it so I can't answer that. Regarding your validation code, don't presume that user input is valid. You do that with $validate=true. Every user input is presumed to be tainted so presume that $validate=false and check if it's true. Also, you should send your validated data with an array or an object with all the inputed values in it.